# How to post the javscript score variable to the view in the django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, django-views

I am developing the quiz application using JavaScript, Django. I stuck at the posting the variable into the Django (DB). I am not getting idea how to post the score  variable  of Java script along with the name which the user logged  into the application. I will share the code of the JavaScript.

Note: Here I didn't used the views.py to calculate score of user. Entire thing I used the JavaScript to validate and to calculate the score.

I got three questions from this:

- How to get the variable value from the JavaScript to the Django views? Please tell me the way.
- Can we use the ajax to post  variable value into the Django views.
- If the value is displaying in the html template. For suppose my score value is storing in the score variable in JavaScript and displaying in the html . I want that value into my  Django views. Then how to get that value  from the javascript?
  Note: Here score is not storing in the form. It is an individual variable

### HTML:- In this place the score will displays

```
<div id="result" class="result" style="display:none;"></div>
```

### JavaScript:-

```
  var resultCont = document.getElementById('result');
if (currentQuestion == totQuestions) {
      resultCont.style.display = '';
      console.log(score);
      if(score == 0 || score < 40)
      {
          resultCont.innerHTML = 'Your Score: ' + score + '/80'+ 'Fail';
      }
      else {
        resultCont.innerHTML = 'Your Score: ' + score + '/80' + 'Pass';
    }

      return;
    }
```

### Now coming to the models.py:

```
class Results(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    quizname = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField()
```

I have this code now but

1. how to write the views.py?
2. what I need to work in JavaScript file  to post into the DB with(username, quizname, score).

Comment: Yes,I too want this answer I am also searching for this. Please help me too.

Comment: you have two choices: 
1. make a button to the end of the quiz that post the score.
2. ajax post request

Comment: how to make an ajax post request to the  Django view . Can you please explain me.

Comment: What I need to put in the views.py for this ajax . Can you please tell me any suggestion .

Comment: @Florin I just created the button but how to store in the DB can You please give me clarity . Please : - ) Please give me  any other link to refer or else explain it properly

Comment: @Florin can you please provide the sample code please yarr. I want the code badly : - (

Answer (score 1):

Just found your second question about that quiz. 
I copied code from my project that I made really long time ago, so just don't judge me for not clean code, errors and mistakes(at least everything is working) :) I made that in Polish, so I translated to English just main info but not questions and answers. I hope you'll understand the logic of my quiz and that code could help you.

```js
//array of question and answers
var data_array = [
   ["Do czego służy polecenie Drugipunkt w AutoCAD?","Umożliwia wskazanie środka łuku.", "Pozwala na narysowanie łuku przechodzącego przez 3 różne punkty.","Umożliwia określenie kierunku rysowania łuku.","Żadna odpowiedź nie jest poprawna.",2],
        
   ["Jaką role wykonuje NFRAGM?","Służy do powiększania i przesuwania rysunku na ekranie.","Dla nawigacji między listami.","Pierwsza i druga odpowiedzi są poprawne.","Nie wiem.",1],
        
   ["Jak stworzyć nowy blok na bazie wybranych elementów?","Rysuj – Figure – Blok ...","Opcje - Stworzyć - Blok ... ","Nowy – Blok – Utwórz ... ","Rysuj – Blok – Utwórz ... ",4],
        
   ["Do czego służy polecenie atrdef?","Automatycznie zmienia wartośći atrubutów.","Ulatwia rysowanie obiekyów.","Wyświetla okno dialogowe Definicja atrybutu.","Polecenie nie istnieje.",3],
        
   ["Które rozszerzenie określa plik szablonu AutoCAD?","DWT","DXF","DWG","CAD",3],
        
   ["Jaki ciąg znakówodpowiada symbolu średnicy okręgu ø ?","%%c","%%d","%%b","%%s",1],
 ];
    
 var plus = 0;
 var time = 0;
 var cur_answer = 0;
 var count_answer = data_array.length;
 
 function sec() {
  time++; 
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML='Passing time: ' + time + ' sec';
 }
 
 function check(num){

  if(num == 0){ 
  
   document.getElementById('option1').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('option2').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('option3').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('option4').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('question').style.display='block';

   document.getElementById('option1').innerHTML=data_array[cur_answer][1];
   document.getElementById('option2').innerHTML=data_array[cur_answer][2];
   document.getElementById('option3').innerHTML=data_array[cur_answer][3];
   document.getElementById('option4').innerHTML=data_array[cur_answer][4];
   document.getElementById('question').innerHTML=data_array[cur_answer][0];
   
   document.getElementById('start').style.display='none';
   document.getElementById('end').style.display='inline';
   
   var intervalID = setInterval(sec, 1000);
   
  }else{

   if( num ==  data_array[cur_answer][5]){
    plus++;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML='Your answer is correct!';
   }else{
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML="Incorrect! Good answer is: " + data_array[cur_answer][data_array[cur_answer][5]];
   }
    
   cur_answer++;
   if(cur_answer < count_answer){
   
    document.getElementById('option1').innerHTML=data_array[cur_answer][1];
    document.getElementById('option2').innerHTML=data_array[cur_answer][2];
    document.getElementById('option3').innerHTML=data_array[cur_answer][3];
    document.getElementById('option4').innerHTML=data_array[cur_answer][4];
    document.getElementById('question').innerHTML=data_array[cur_answer][0];
    
   }else{
    
    document.getElementById('time').id = 'stop';
    document.getElementById('option1').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('option2').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('option3').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('option4').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('question').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('end').style.display='inline';
    
    var percent =  Math.round(plus/count_answer*100);    
    var res = 'You are Junior!';
    if(percent>70) res = 'You are Med-Level!';
    if(percent==100) res = 'You are Senior! Congratulation!';
    
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML='Correct answers: ' + plus + ' out of ' + count_answer + ' (' + percent + '%)<br>' + res;
   }
  }
 }
```

```css
body{
    background: #fff url(img/bg1.jpg); 
    color: #fff; 
   
 font-family:verdana;
 color:#444;
}
p{
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

#option1,#option2,#option3,#option4{
 display:none;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.test1{
     background-color: #6cb670;
    border: 1px;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
    .test2{
     background-color: #088A68;
    border: 1px;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
 <center>   
  <p id="time">Passing time: 0 sek</p>
  <p id="result"></p>
  <p id="question"></p>
  
  <button onclick="check(1)" class="test1" id="option1"></button>
  
  <button onclick="check(2)" class="test1" id="option2"></button>
  
  <button onclick="check(3)" class="test1" id="option3"></button>
  
  <button onclick="check(4)" class="test1" id="option4"></button>
 </center><br>
 <center>
  <button id="start" class="test2" onclick="check(0)">Start</button>
  <script type="text/javascript"> var curent_url = document.URL; document.write("<a id='end' style='display: none;' class='test2' href='" + curent_url + "'>Start again!</a>"); </script> 
 </center><br><br>
 <center style="clear:both;"><br>

  <a class="test2" href="index.html">Home<i class="fa fa-home fa"></i> </a>
 </center>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also you can check here, just more comfortable :)
https://codepen.io/alona-yavorska/pen/zYvXvEv?editors=1010

Comment: Thank you actually the timer is working :-) which you shared the link tqsm

Comment: i didn't find any django here ??? only javascript is there i just want to pass the js score existing variable to the django view.